# How should I add django import export on the User Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-import-export

I am trying to enable django import export on the django user model. 
I have tried defining a model admin class, unregistering the user model and then registering the new user admin class. But it doesn't work.

my admin.py looks like this -

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseAdmin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources

class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class UserAdmin(BaseAdmin, ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = UserResource

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I want to know how can I achieve this? Is there some other way I can apply django import export on the user model?

Comment: Have you installed `django-import-export` and added it to the INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: And i do not see the lines where you are importing `ModelResource` and `ImportExportModelAdmin` in your code.

Comment: i have skipped adding there although i edited it now. It works fine for other models but not for the user model

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. You just need to import the User model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```